# Understanding Haskell basics?

Tags: haskell

I have somethig like this :

```
String "[apple,mango]"
```

How can I extract apple and mango ? is there I way I can get List out of above expression ?

Comment: What is `String`?

Comment: I think you really should indicate what you're trying to do as well as any code you've attempted as well as explaining your thought process. There are many possible things you could mean, depending on your level of understanding of these things. The fact that you've written your code the way you have makes me think that it's quite possible you need to learn some much more fundmanetal things than String parsing first. I don't mean to sound rude or condescending, it's that what might seem like a simple thing quite probably isn't. It might help a lot to read the tutorial I helped write explicitly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What type are `apple` and `mango`? If you have created a Fruit type with several value constructors they should be capitalized like `Apple | Mango | Banana ...`  and you can then do like

```
read "[Apple, Mango]" :: [Fruit]
```

However if they are String type then your string should be like `"[\"apple\",\"mango\"]"` and you can then read them like

```
read "[\"apple\",\"mango\"]" :: [String]
```